# Customize isearch to start from buffer start

Tags: isearch

`Ctrl-s`, `isearch-forward` is not appealing to me and so, i wrote a wrapper around it to search from the beginning of the buffer always.

```
(defun sk-isearch-forward (original)
  (interactive "sEnter search string:  ")
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (isearch-forward original)))
```

Now, i am seeing two issues:::

1) `M-x sk-isearch-forward` goes to the beginning of the buffer but never returns to the original cursor position. `save-excursion` is added to take care of this but it is failing me

2) it is not highlighting any of the matching words in the current buffer.

Is `isearch-forward` not the right function for this job?

I always search for a word, no regexes and the search, i prefer to start from the beginning. How can i do this?

Comment: @Name, please make it as the answer... thanks, Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the argument, i.e.

```lisp
(defun sk-isearch-forward () 
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (isearch-forward)))
```

Comment: Thanks @lawlist I modified it. The OP wants to return to the original cursor position as stated in the question, so `save-excursion` seems to be the right choice in this situation.

Comment: how is  `(beginning-of-buffer)` different from `(goto-char (point-min))`?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Check out the docstring of `beginning-of-buffer` by using `C-h f` to learn that.

Comment: Reproducing the relevant section of `beginning-of-buffer`'s docstring for the benefit of others - `Don't use this (beginning-of-buffer) command in Lisp programs!
(goto-char (point-min)) is faster)`